# iOS device not receiving push notification from Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: ios, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

I've created an Ionic chat app with firebase cloud functions.  The push notifications are working with Android but not ios.

```js
  async getIosToken(token: string, userId: string): Promise<void> {
    if (!FCM.hasPermission()) {
      FCM.requestPushPermission()
        .then(async (hasPerm) => {
          if (hasPerm) {
            const iosToken = await FCM.getAPNSToken();
            if (iosToken === token) {
              return;
            } else {
              this.saveToken(iosToken, userId);
            }
          }
        });
    } else {
      const iosToken = await FCM.getAPNSToken();
      if (iosToken === token) {
        return;
      } else {
        this.saveToken(iosToken, userId);
      }
    }
  }

  saveToken(token: string, userId: string): void {
    this.userSvc.saveTokenToFirestore(token, userId)
      .then(() => {
        this.storageSvc.setDeviceToken(token);
      });
  }
```

The iOS token is being saved to firebase...although it never prompted the user for request permissions.

I console logged the firebase cloud function and I can see the APNs token.

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

exports.newChatNotification = functions.firestore
.document(`chat/{id}/messages/{doc}`)
.onWrite(async event => {
    const message = event.after.data();
    let data: any;
    let device: any;

    const db = admin.firestore();
    console.log('message', message);
    console.log('db', db);

    if (message) { data = message; }
    const receivingUserId = data ? data.receivingUserId : '';
    const content = data ? data.content : '';
    const sendingUserId = data ? data.sendingUserId : '';
    console.log('payload', receivingUserId, sendingUserId);

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'New message',
            body: `${content}`,
            click_action: 'FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY'
        },
        data: {
           page: 'tabs/travel-buddies',
        }
    };

    console.log('payload2', payload);
    const devicesRef = (await db.collection('devices').doc(`${receivingUserId}`).get()).data();
    if (devicesRef) { device = devicesRef; }
    const token = device ? device.token : '';
    console.log('devicesRef', devicesRef, token);
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
});
```

Here's the firebase cloud function console

[image: message log]

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot why ios is not receiving a push notification because there aren't any errors and I'm getting the APNs token.

I've also tried updating the build system per Google searches online:
[image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated.